# View and Controller 1:1 relationship. Instantiate the View in the Controller? A better way?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I currently create the `View` and inject it into the requested `Controller` and then I do

```
$this->view->load('sometemplate');
```

and then at the end of my startup.php file I do

```
$view->render();
```

I am now changing my application to have a `View` per `Controller` but the only way I can think of doing that is to instantiate the `View` in the `Controller` since every `Controller` will have a unique `View` instance.

**Edit**

If I have a `Controllers\Products` I want it to have a `Views\Products`. The easiest way to do that would be to instantiate the `Views\Products` inside `Controllers\Products` because when I am in the `Controller` I will know exactly what `View` I need but I do not like the idea of instantiating a `View` in a `Controller`.

I would prefer to create `Views\Products` outside `Controllers\Products` and inject it in.

My `Router::route($uri)` returns a `Route` with these properties

```
private $directory;
private $controller; // Just controller name, not an instance
private $method;
private $params = array();
```

I was thinking maybe if my `Views` and `Controllers` have the same names I could use the `$controller` property from the `Route` to instantiate the correct `View` and then inject that into the correct `Controller`. Would this be a good way?

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the best way to maintain the decoupled nature of the MVC pattern?

Comment: Is what the best way? Having a `View` per `Controller`?

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Do you expect to use multiple controllers per execution?

Comment: Updated the main part above.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about MVC, then I will say you must have actions inside your controller classes.
according to the convention, your view classes should have same names as of your actions.